# Only seeing one output in results pane

Tags: linqpad

If I run C# statements in Linqpad

```
var doc = "<a></a>";
doc.Dump();
doc.Dump();
```

I see two lines in the result pane

But if I do

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<a></a>");
doc.Dump();
doc.Dump();
```

I see just one line in the result pane

```
<a></a>
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you dump an XDocument or an XElement, LINQPad instantiates a custom visualizer with syntax coloring for XML. Each document is displayed in its own window, so you'll notice two tabs in the results area (both labelled 'XML').